# How can I bind data into Xaml, Windows Phone?

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

This is my C# code, now it's showing data in console.

```
class PlaceViewModel
    {

        public List<Vantaa.IntroPage.Place> Places;
    }       

public class Place
            {
                public string id { get; set; }
                public string title { get; set; }
                public string latitude { get; set; }
                public string longitude { get; set; }
                public string www { get; set; }
            }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Place> Places { get; set; }
        }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mobiilivantaa.lightscreenmedia.com/api/place"));
        }

        private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

            foreach (var book in rootObject.Places)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(book.id);
            }
            this.DataContext = new PlaceViewModel
                 {
                      Places = rootObject.Places
                 };
            }
```

What should I do with xaml file in order to show the data in textblock ?

This is my current xaml code. It's surely not working. I really have no idea.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class-code looks good so now it's just a matter of binding the results to the view. You are returning a list of objects so you should use a control that supports showing multiple items. Of course you could concatenate all the id's of the books to one string and show it in a label. But this is not how it's done. What you should do is add a ListBox control to the XAML and create a DataTemplate inside it. This way you set the way items will be displayed.

Create a class that will be the ViewModel for your XAML-page. This class will have a property 'Places' (type: `List<Place>`). In the OnNavigatedTo-event when getting all the data is done, fill the ViewModel and bind and bind it to the DataContext of the XAML:

```
this.DataContext = new YourViewModel { Places = rootObject.Places };
```

This way you can grab all the objects from the ViewModel in your XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

***Edit:***

Here's a working example:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**Place.cs:**

```
public class Place
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Web { get; set; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Places = new List<Place>();
    }

    public List<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample repository (you should have your own):**

```
public static List<Place> FetchData()
{
    var lst = new List<Place>();

    lst.Add(new Place { ID = "1", Title = "One", Latitude = "111", Longitude = "111", Web = "www......" });
    lst.Add(new Place { ID = "2", Title = "Two", Latitude = "222", Longitude = "222", Web = "www......" });
    lst.Add(new Place { ID = "3", Title = "Three", Latitude = "333", Longitude = "333", Web = "www......" });
    lst.Add(new Place { ID = "4", Title = "Four", Latitude = "444", Longitude = "444", Web = "www......" });

    return lst;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //This is where the magic happens
    //Fill the viewModel with the data
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel { Places = Repository.FetchData() };
    //Assign the viewModel with the data to the DataContext
    //The bindings will be automatically done in the XAML
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Dit you create a ViewModel-class? Did you fill the property with the fetched data? Dit you assign the ViewModel to the DataContext?

Comment: Mate, You showed a sample repository and you told have your own. How can i fill that with dynamic data ?

Comment: That's material for a separate question... :D Anyway, you can have a database and use an Object Relation Mapper like the Entitiy Framework, this creates objects from your tables. This way you can communicate with the object through LinQ. The repository is a class with all kinds of methods for adding/updating/deleting data. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Your PlaceViewModel class should implement INotifyProprtyChanged interface and all properties that you want to bind should notify their changes in setters.

To be able to update values in bound textblock, a property could notify its change.

Example: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx

Comment: +1 for the tip of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, but I think in this case the basic binding will do. But you're absolutely right when advancing to a higher level of binding! :)