# Display multiple local database value in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to list out data from a local database to a list box for WP8.1

.xaml:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
            <Image Source= "**Fruit Image**" Height="26" Width="50" Margin="12,10,9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Text="**Fruit Name**"  FontSize="26" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="**Fruit Colour**"  FontSize="26" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Getting value from my database

.cs:

```
public void ListFruit()
{
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
    {
        List<Fruits> retrievedTasks = db.Table<Fruits>().ToList<Fruits>();
    }
}
```

.cs

```
public class Fruits
{
    public string ImgPath { get; set; }
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
    public string FruitColour{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm not really sure if the method i'm using is correct, please guide me. Thanks!

Comment: Post your ListBox Xaml binding part!

Comment: I've provided two answers on questions that address a similar problem: [How can I bind data into Xaml, Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153659/how-can-i-bind-data-into-xaml-windows-phone/14153702#14153702) or [How can I data bind a list of strings to a ListBox in WPF/WP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391746/how-can-i-data-bind-a-list-of-strings-to-a-listbox-in-wpf-wp7/9391815#9391815)

Comment: I've yet to do the bind cause I don't really have the idea how to start with. @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined properties in your class, you have filled your `List<Fruit>` with items.
What you should else do is (if you haven't done it already):

Define your `List<Fruit>` as ItemsSource of Listbox

```
public void ListFruit()
{
  using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
  {
      List<Fruits> retrievedTasks = db.Table<Fruits>().ToList<Fruits>();
      myListbox.ItemsSource = retrievedTasks; // or directly
  }
}
```

You may also think of using `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` - in this case you need to set `ItemsSource` only once - for example in constructor of the Page. You may also think of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that you can inform View when item changes.

And I'm not sure if you had defined Binding in your xaml (or somewhere else):

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
            <Image Source= "{Binding ImgPath}" Height="26" Width="50" Margin="12,10,9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitName}"  FontSize="26" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitColour}"  FontSize="26" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: ObservableCollection is much easier to understand and use. Thanks for the help!